# multiple nil, nil, ... detection in Go

Tags: go, null

In go you can have several returns like:

```
func getAdressParts() (plz *string, street *string) {
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {

    //if getAdressParts() == nil, nill {
    //   println(true)
    //} else {
    //   println(false)
    //}

    // As already suggested the answer is:
    if plz, street := getAdressParts(); plz == nil && street == nil {
        println("Hurra")
    } else {
        println("nope")
    }

}
```

is there any way to check both inline for nil like:

```
if getAdressParts() == nil, nil {
   ...
}
```

you can play with example here: https://play.golang.org/p/xbHCxl_AJyw

Comment: `nil` is not a valid value for the `string` type, so even a check like `plz == nil` is a compile time error.

Comment: yes, sorry I was to quick with the post, and missed that, the question has been updated in the meantime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite that succinctly, but yes:

```
if plz, street := getAdressParts(); plz == nil && street == nil {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This is demonstrated in [the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6) and [the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements).

Note as icza points out, this doesn't make any sense for `string`s (which can't be `nil`), but the syntax you'd use for a valid test is as above.

Comment: Yeah, but the impression I got from the question was it's about the syntax of an inline `nil` check, not literally checking if a `string` is `nil` or not. Updated answer to add that note just in case.

Comment: yes sorry was just about to update the question, you´ve been too fast :) but the answer is good!

Answer (score 3):

string can't be nil, but i think you'll need to do

```
if a, b := getAdressParts(); a == "" && b == "" {
    println("nil")
}
```

Comment: what about `a+b==""`? Is not more costly than yours?

Comment: In the case where a or b is not empty, that seems more expensive as it'll require an allocation and 2 copes.